# How to prove total test error is independent of the selected learning algorithm

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

I'm looking at the following proof:

[image: test error]

Where:

Note: I'm new to this but I *think* I understand all the below variables correctly now. Mistakes are possible though.

- $f$ is an ideal function with perfect results with respect to some sample set
- $\sum_{h}$ is the hypothesis space
- $\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}-X}$ is the sum of the entire sample space *except* the training data
- $P(x)$ is the probability distribution over the sample space
- The binary function in the middle is a selection function for any instance where a hypothesis is selected that is not an ideal function
- $P(h | X, L_a)$ is the probability distribution of selecting hypothesis $h$ given some function/learned model $L_a)$ used on training data $X$

The author says that given some learning function $X -> \{0,1\}$ it's function space would be $\{0,1\}^{|x|}$. He furthermore says

> if $f$ is uniformly distributed, half of the predictions of $f$ on $X$
> are not consistent with $h(X)$

I do not understand what is meant by this nor how he arrived at that conclusion. Why would it be the case that if $f$ is uniformly distributed that half of its predictions are not consistent with $h(X)$?

After showing this proof he then goes on to say that test error, $E_{ote}$, is independent of the chosen algorithm ($L_a$)

Comment: I think these machine learning questions would be better on another SE site, perhaps https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Joe if that is the case what is the function of the machine learning tag?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I just see way more ML questions on other sites, and very few on here.

Comment: But to answer your question, the idea is that, the set $f$ can be organized in pairs that completely disagree with each other outside the training set. So on average each pair differs with $h$ on 1/2 of the points outside the training set.

Comment: For example, if $f_1$ predicts true on every point outside the training set, and $f_2$ predicts false on every point outside the training set, and there are $n$ points outside the training set; then if $h$ disagrees with $f_1$ on $k$ points, $h$ must disagree with $f_2$ on $n-k$ points, and on average it disagrees with the pair on $n/2$ points

Comment: @Joe I appreciate the help! How do you arrive at the conclusion each pair differs with $h$ on 1/2 points outside the training set?

Comment: (Feel free to point me to a reading resource if there is one. I've had trouble coming up with machine learning specific resources)

Comment: I took this course http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~magdon/courses/learn.php

Comment: The book is $28 here https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1600490069

Comment: The lectures are currently on YouTube, which can be found by searching “learning from data Malik”, or currently at this link - http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~magdon/courses/ONLINElearn.php

Comment: The main idea is that, if your hypothesis set is the set of ALL binary classifiers on the data space, then the learned hypothesis will exactly match the training data, but if there are $n$ points outside the training data, there are $2^n$ hypotheses that match the training data. The learning algorithm can only pick one at random, and the expected OTE is $n/2$. The book explains that this is why we want to use smaller hypothesis sets, which it explains in terms of “VC dimension”.

Comment: @Joe just wanted to let you know I hadn't forgotten about this. I'm working on the second lecture (perceptron) and the book gets here tomorrow. Parts of the explanation above make sense to me but I'm still a bit hazy based on the other book I read. The lectures you linked definitely provide a lot more background than the book I had which pretty much just launched into things.

Comment: Which book were you using? I really enjoyed Professor Magdon-Ismail's course, and book. When you get to section 1.3 "Is Learning Feasible", it will explain this question, including "Probability to the Rescue", which explains how we "can reach outside $\mathcal{D}$"

Comment: 机器学习  - directly translated, machine learning. I like it a lot but it assumes a lot of math knowledge and college was a ways back for me. https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/7302423288/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o06_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Joe for suggesting the resources to answer this. The below two pictures from "Learning from Data - A Short Course" (which I would suggest) are what made this problem clear to me.

#### Deriving the 1/2

In the picture $g$ is the selected hypothesis. Let's say that $g$ matches $f_1$. Now we calculate how much disagreement there is with $g$ and all the other $f$s.

- $f_1$ = 0 (since this is the one we picked)
- $f_2$ = 1
- $f_3$ = 1
- $f_4$ = 2
- $f_5$ = 1
- $f_6$ = 2
- $f_7$ = 2
- $f_8$ = 3

The average disagreement then is the sum of $(0+1+1+2+1+2+2+3)/8=1.5$. There are 3 points outside of the training set so in this case our hypothesis disagrees with exactly $1.5/3=1/2$ of the other possible hypothesis. Now to my original question, I asked why does it matter that $f$ is uniformly distributed. Notice that the only reason the above works is that every $f$ completely disagrees with every other $f$ *outside the training data*. If there were agreement between some of the $f$s the math would no longer hold up.

#### Deriving the ^2

This is really less of a derivation and more just requires some logical thought about the nature of binary. Look at the chart of the various $f$s mapped. Notice again, assuming that all the $f$s completely disagree with each other, there are exactly $2^n$ which agree with the training data. Think about it logically - if all $f$s must disagree and you only have 3 bits, then there are only 8 possibilities. It does not matter what the training data is, the points outside the training data only have 8 possibilities before they would start to overlap. This scales to any number of points. $n$ could be a billion and this would still be true.

[image: page 1][image: page 2]